# "Picture Frame" mode on modern iPad

Tags: ipad, photos

I have an iPad 1 with iOS 5. This is a "Picture Frame" mode which sports the following features:

- Start slideshow from lock screen ("Flower" icon)
- Show photo on whole screen with calm dissolve effect
- Show photos in random order

A friend has a modern iPad with iOS 11. Here, the "Picture Frame" mode seems to be gone. However, there is a "Play" button in the photo album. This is how it works:

- Start slideshow from inside photo album
- Show collage of photos with various hefty effects
- Show photos in sequential order (Starts at beginning every time)

How can I make a modern iPad show photos like the old iPad, ie. on the *whole screen*, with a *subtle transition* effect, and most importantly, in *random order*?

Answer (score 1):

For the built-in Photos app, you can get subtle effects (dissolve, specifically, is available) in full screen of iOS 11, but I can’t find a way to randomise it, unfortunately.

Since I never used the picture-frame mode on my iPad 1, I can’t *picture* it (heh) in my head, but if you go to Photos → Your Album and choose *Start Slideshow*, you can tap on the slideshow and on the bottom right an **Options** button will be revealed, allowing you to change the speed of the transitions, toggle *Repeat* , choose or disable an accompanying musical theme, and choose the transition type (which includes **Dissolve**)

I’m not familiar with other slideshow applications, so I can’t suggest any.